# What does 'Linear regularities among words' mean?

Tags: nlp, language-model, representation

**Context**: In the paper ["Efficient Estimation of Word Representations in Vector Space"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.3781) by T. Mikolov et al., the authors make use of the phrase: 'Linear regularities among words'.

What does that mean in the context of the paper, or in a general context related to NLP?

Quoting the paragraph from the paper:

> Somewhat surprisingly, it was found that similarity of word
>   representations goes beyond simple syntactic regularities. Using a
>   word offset technique where simple algebraic operations are performed
>   on the word vectors, it was shown for example that vector(”King”) -
>   vector(”Man”) + vector(”Woman”) results in a vector that is closest to
>   the vector representation of the word Queen [20].
>
> In this paper, we try to maximize accuracy of these vector operations
>   by developing new model architectures that preserve **the linear
>   regularities among words**. We design a new comprehensive test set for
>   measuring both syntactic and semantic regularities1 , and show that
>   many such regularities can be learned with high accuracy. Moreover, we
>   discuss how training time and accuracy depends on the dimensionality
>   of the word vectors and on the amount of the training data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By linear regularities among words, he meant that "Vectorized form of words should follow linear additive properties!"

V("King") - V("Man") + V("Woman") ~ V("Queen)